# argurments not being passed on edit action, nested objects

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write an edit action for a my post object which is nested inside the projects one. By the looks of it I'm doing everything as it should be but for some reason when I comes down to load the form, this error message appears "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

The params being sent are correct "project_id"=>"308", "id"=>"41", however it seems like the form does not know what to do with them.

form

```
.....
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="postform">
    <%= form_for ([@project, @post]), html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>

....
```

view

```
....
<% if current_user?(post.user) %>
                    <%= link_to edit_project_post_path(@project, post ) do %>
....
```

controller

```
....

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :edit]

    def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @post = @project.posts.find(params[:id])
    end
....
```

post is a nested object of projects and so it has been config on the route  s file.

Any ideas what might be causing this problem?

I thought that maybe I need to specify on the form what are these values used for...

Thanks for the help

---- Edit ----

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments,:posts
  end

resources :posts,              only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
```

Comment: Based on the error message it tells you that `@project` in the `form_for ([@project, @post])` is either `nil` or `[]`. Can you paste `rake routes` for those pages?

Comment: `<%= form_for([@project, @post], html: { multipart: true })  do |f| %>`. If you are going to use parens wrap all the arguments!

Comment: However the error does not seem to be in the code provided. Have you tried taking the problem apart? For example by doing `[@project, @post].inspect` to check that you are not inadvertently reassigning the variables somewhere? Or maybe you are rescuing the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error in your controller without exiting the controller flow?

Answer (score 0):

form_for is not supposed to work with multipart: true, try removing that or try with form_tag.

Best regards.